# Can you do automated feature engineering in R?

Tags: r, feature-engineering

Since now Python has its own [deep feature synthesis](https://www.featuretools.com/) library, is there anything similar available in R? I know of [bounceR](https://github.com/STATWORX/bounceR) but I'm not sure if it does the job as DFS does. Is anyone aware of anything similar in R?

Comment: There exists a wrapper for that Python library in R on CRAN: https://github.com/magnusfurugard/featuretoolsR

Comment: Thanks a million!

Comment: @aranglol: you should post that as an answser.